# How to specify 3GB using bit shift in python?

Tags: python-3.x, bit-manipulation, tensorrt

I am allocating memory in the Jetson TX2. It has 8GB of RAM.
I need to specify the maximun GPU memory size available for TensorRT.

> max_workspace_size_bytes = (has to be an integer)

I have seen some examples using these "values":

```
1<<20 = 1048576 (decimal)
      = 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000

1<<30 = 1073741824
      = 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

But if I have 8GB of RAM, how can "1048576" or "1073741824" represent a part of RAM?

I have used this to allocate 3GB:

```
3*(10**9)
```

But I would like to understand the other way of representing a number.

Comment: The example values are a bit off, 65536 = 1<<16 and 16777216 = 1 <<24 (you can see that easily in the binary representation by counting the trailing zeroes)

Comment: ok. I will check the calculator that I have used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sum them up.

```
((1<<30)+(1<<31))
```

Or bitwise OR them.

```
((1<<30) | (1<<31))
```

Or shift a larger value than 1, e.g. 3.

```
(3<<30)
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're having a "Gb vs G**i**b" problem. Usually, 3 Gigas of RAM refers to 3,221,225,472 bytes instead of 3,000,000,000.

The first value is 3 * (2^10)*(2^10)*(2^10), a nice 3 (11) followed by 30 zeros in binary representation, while the second is 3 * (10^3)*(10^3)*(10^3), which is a mess in binary.

This convention of using powers of 2 instead of powers of 10 is the reason why you'll see people writing a 3Gb as `3 << 30`:

```
3 << 30 == 3 * (1 << 10) * (1 << 10) * (1 << 10)
        == 3 * (2**10 * 2**10 * 2**10)
        == 3 * (2**30)
```

There's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365100/converting-bytes-to-megabytes?noredirect=1&lq=1) and a good [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix) about this issue if you want to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

```
3GB = 3,221,225,472
      1100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

3<<30 = 3GB
```